# Is py:method needed for docstring info field lists?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using sphinx-apidoc to gather documentation from Python docstrings.

In order to obtain formatted `Parameters`, `Returns`, `Raises` and other sphinx documentation sections, it seems I need to put `.. py:method::` or other similar domain representations, as shown in this trivial class:

```
class Message(object):
    """
    .. py:class::
       Base class representing a message.
    """

    DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 5

    def __init__(self):
        """
        .. py:method::
           Constructor.
        """
        self.priority = Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY

    def set_priority(self, priority):
        """
        .. py:method::
           Set the message priority.

        :param int priority: The new message priority.
        :return: The old message priority.
        :rtype: int
        :raise TypeError: The given priority is not an int.
        """
        if not isinstance(priority, int):
            raise TypeError
        old_priority = priority
        self.priority = priority
        return old_priority
```

Without `.. py:method` etc. the parameters, returns, etc. are unformatted on a single line.

Are these necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `.. py:method` part is not needed.  What is needed is a newline separating the description from the `:param` and other blocks, as:

```
class Message(object):
    """
    Base class representing a message.
    """

    DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 5

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor.
        """
        self.priority = Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY

    def set_priority(self, priority):
        """
        Set the message priority.

        :param int priority: The new message priority.
        :return: The old message priority.
        :rtype: int
        :raise TypeError: The given priority is not an int.
        """
        if not isinstance(priority, int):
            raise TypeError
        old_priority = priority
        self.priority = priority
        return old_priority
```